# Django Rest Framwork - Put FileField value into response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

in my Django Rest Framwork project, I have the following view:

```
class RegistrationView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = {}

        # check if email exists
        ...

        # check if username exists
        ...

        # at this point, we know everything is ok -> the serializer can do its work
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'registered new user'
            data['id'] = account.id
            data['email'] = account.email
            data['username'] = account.username
            data['profile_pic'] = account.profile_pic     <--- HERE the problem occurs!!
            data['date_joined'] = account.date_joined
            token = Token.objects.get(user=account)
            data['token'] = token.key
        else:
            data = serializer.errors

        return Response(data)
```

I tried to put the result of the registration process into `data` dictionary which is then returned as response to the user. But in the line where I have `data['profile_pic'] = account.profile_pic` an exception occurs stating this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

The `profile_pic` field of the `Account` model is a `FileField` as you can see in the following:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    profile_pic = models.FileField(upload_to='Images/',default='Images/None/placeholder.jpg')
```

How can I get the value of the `FileField` which basically points to the profile picture of the `Account`.

Comment: You can use the URL, right?

Comment: which URL do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Use URL of files:

```
data['profile_pic'] = account.profile_pic.url
```